# Accessing report output table in Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have written an SQL query to return an **Interactive report** in APEX, and I would like to create another (**classic**) report on the same page that summarizes that report. The report gives test results, and I want to summarize it by grade level (so x # of As, y Bs, etc)

It's a complicated query that takes a while to run, so I'd like to avoid just running it again and using aggregation functions.

Does APEX store that report in a variable or table as it does variables (something like `:TABLE_NAME`) that I could just run a query on? I haven't been able to find anything on that in documentation or searching.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One option is to

- enter parameters you use to filter data in that complex query
- instead of running the report directly, create a push button and a process on it
- that process should insert the result into a global temporary table (GTT) you'd, of course, have to create

  - why? Because it can be shared by multiple users, while everyone sees only their own data
- interactive report would fetch & display data from the GTT
- classic report would summarize data from the GTT

Comment: Thanks! I haven't worked with GTTs at all and am fairly new to APEX, but some other comments on threads about GTTs in APEX suggest using APEX Collections instead. Do you have any opinions on one versus the other?

Comment: You're welcome. From my point of view, tables are simpler to use.

Comment: I'd go for collections - that is more robust. With a GTT you're limited to your database session. Apex is stateless so it doesn't guarantee you always have the same database session. You risk that the user keeps open the page and partially refreshes the page 15 minutes later. At that point you most likely get a different db session and your GTT data is gone.

Comment: Right; makes a lot of sense, @Koen.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts, @KoenLostrie!